# How do I access process from node in a tauri vite app

Tags: vite, tauri

I am trying to use a kubernetes-client library from here https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript in a tauri app. However, it depends on `process` from `node` which is not available in tauri.

What are my options?

Can I modify the source code of the library in place within `node_modules` like

```
import { api } from "tauri";
const process = api.process();

# Original code from library below
var version = process.version;
```

if so how do I ensure my changes reflect?

Alternatively should I use a plugin or similar workarounds that could help me with this?